# Using 2 color functions in a mathematica matrix plot

Tags: function, colors, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use 2 color functions within one matrix plot in mathematica. Is this possible to do?

For example, using a very simple matrix:

```
test = Partition[Table[i, {i, 1, 9}], 3]
```

I would like to make the even numbers vary in color increasing from white to red; and the odd numbers vary in color from grey to black.

How could I do this? I know how to get the whole matrix to vary in color, but no more than this.

Comment: [Cross-posting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30736/52) simultaneously across different stackexchange sites is frowned upon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is already cross-posted on Mathematica. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30736/using-two-color-functions-in-a-matrixplot

Answer (score 2):

You could try defining a `ColorFunction` as below.

```
CheckerPlot[array_?MatrixQ] :=
    With[{len = Length[Flatten[array]]}, 
        ArrayPlot[array,
                  ColorFunction->(If[EvenQ[#], Blend[{White, Red}, #/len], 
                                               Blend[{Gray,Black}, #/len]] &), 
                  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
    ]
```

Execute by using, for example,

```
CheckerPlot[Partition[Table[i, {i,1,36}], 5]]
```